# What vocabulary terms describe analyzing code for the "traceback" of a non-function variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, static-analysis

Python is able to provide a trackback for functions, showing what was called along the way during the execution of that function.

I don't yet have the vocabulary to describe this same approach for inspecting / introspecting the history of a non-function object, like a variable that holds an integer or string. Taking the following block of code as an example:

```py
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + 3
```

I am looking to understand what words or concepts to search for to describe getting a "traceback" (I'm using that word very loosely, because I don't yet have a better term to use) for `c`, above. I'd like to arrive at output that would tell me that the code that went into creating `c` is:

```py
a = 1
c = a + 3
```

What terms or concepts are useful to look up to understand how to conceptualize this task? Alternatively, is the above completely off-base based on how Python3 stores variables or how Python3 code works, relating to anything that would prevent a linter / code analyzer from ever being able to perform this type of analysis?

Comment: I don't know of a term similar to "traceback" for this. Changes to variables aren't tracked anywhere, so you need to manage that yourself if you need that information for debugging purposes. If you put `print` calls after every transformation of that data, that's referred to as "print-debugging". That same procedure can be done using breakpoints in an actual debugger.

Comment: The function traceback is a very mechanical thing: it is simply the stack of uncompleted calls at the time of the inciting event.  What you are (apparently) looking for involves something much deeper (for example, that `b = 2` did not contribute to what ended up in `c`).  Static code analysis might at least be related to what you seem to want.

Comment: Thank you both! Your comments have helped me to understand the landscape better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the term you're looking for is [program slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing):

> In computer programming, **program slicing** is the computation of the
> set of program statements, the **program slice**, that may affect the
> values at some point of interest, referred to as a **slicing criterion**.

Comment: This looks like _exactly_ what I was looking for; thank you!